# How can I generate public key for plaid link in JavaScript or asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want this in asp.net mvc or JavaScript, but I didn't find any way as I have also does google it. On the plaid documentation, they do not provide any way to generate a public key in c#.net or JavaScript

please anyone can help me to out to here.

Comment: What is "plaid" in this context?

Comment: Go through the website for more details about plaid==> https://plaid.com/docs/link/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.